# Can't connect 2 divs

Tags: html, css

No matter what I change in my code, the divs *topnav* and *subbanner* won't connect. There's always some space left between them.

I've also been facing problems with picture alignment, but I'm pretty sure I'll be able to solve that eventually. This problem, though, I don't think it'll go away so fast.

Here's the code:

```css
body  { 
 background-color: #0066CC; 
}   

#top  {
 background-color: #333399;
 border-bottom: 1px #eeeeee solid;
 height: 200px;
 width: 900px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 margin: auto;
}

#logo  { 
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 30px ;
 padding: 0;
 float: left; 
 overflow: hidden;
 clear: both;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#logo img {
 margin-top: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 width: 170px;
 height: 170px;
}

#title {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right: 155px;
 text-align: justify;
 height: 150px;
}

#title h1 {
 line-height: 60%;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#title p {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#topnav {
 width: 900px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #333399;
 height: 40px;
 border-top: 2px white solid;
}

#topnav ul { 
 margin-top: 0;
 float: left; 
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0;
}

#topnav ul li { 
 display: inline; 
 background-color: #339999;
}

#topnav ul li a { 
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 float:left; 
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 20px; 
 width: 140px;
}

#topnav a:link  { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:visited { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:active { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:hover  { background-color: #0077CC; }
#topnav a:focus  { color:#ffffff; }

#subbanner {
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #2687D7; 
 width: 900px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 overflow: hidden;
 
}

#subbanner h2 {
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#subbanner p { 
 margin: 0px 150px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}

#dobrodosli { 
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px; 
 margin-right: 15px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-top-style: outset;
 border-right-style: inset;
 border-bottom-style: inset;
 border-left-style: outset;
 border-top-color: DodgerBlue;
 border-left-color: DodgerBlue;
 border-right-color: Cyan;
 border-bottom-color: Cyan;
 vertical-align: middle;
 align: middle;
}

#picture1   { 
 float: right;
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-top-style:outset;
 border-right-style:inset;
 border-bottom-style:inset;
 border-left-style: outset;
 border-top-color: cyan;
 border-left-color: cyan;
 border-right-color: DodgerBlue;
 border-bottom-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Modent - naslovna</title>
<link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
     <div id="logo">
         <a href="index.html"><img src="Slike/logo2.png" /></a>
        </div>
     <div id="title">
         <h1>Zdravstvena ustanova</h1>
         <h1>stomatolo&#353;ka ambulanta</h1>
         <hr/>
         <h1>M O D E N T &nbsp; &nbsp; L O P A R E</h1>
         <p>Cara Du&#353;ana 32 A Lopare</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav">
     <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Naslovna</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">O nama</a></li>
   <li><a href="team.html">Tim</a></li>
   <li><a href="galerija.html">Galerija</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="subbanner">
     <h2>Dobrodo&#353;li u Modent!</h2><br />
        <img id="dobrodosli" src="Slike/dobrodosli.jpg" /><img id="picture1" src="Slike/op_1.jpg" />
        <p>Zdravstvena ustanova stomatoloska ambulanta <b><i>MODENT Lopare</i></b> pocela je sa radom 03.02.2004.                       godine. Organizovana je na taj nacin da strucnim radom i visoko profesionalnom stomatoloskom aparaturom           pruzi sve usluge pacijentima iz oblasti stomatoloske zdravstvene zastite.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

Remove overflow and add padding-top

```
#subbanner {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #2687D7; 
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 1px; 

}
```

**Another way:**

```
#subbanner {
    ...
    //overflow: hidden;
    ... 
}
#subbanner h2{
    ....
    margin-top: 0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS code `#topnav ul` 's `height` to `10px`.

```
#topnav ul { 
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left; 
    height: 40px; /*change the height to 10px it will work */
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A browser automatically gives ul-elements a margin. You can overwrite this by adding 'margin-bottom: 0;' to '#topnav ul' as shown in the code below:

```
#topnav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only add `margin-bottom:0` like this :**

```
#topnav ul { 

    margin-bottom: 0;

   //More code...

}
```

**Full Code :**

```css
body        { 
            background-color: #0066CC; 
            }        
                
#top        {
    background-color: #333399;
    border-bottom: 1px #eeeeee solid;
    height: 200px;
    width: 900px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
     }
     
#logo       { 
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px ;
    padding: 0;
    float: left; 
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
#logo img   {
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    }
    
#title {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 155px;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 150px;
    }

#title h1 {
    line-height: 60%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#title p {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
#topnav {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #333399;
    height: 40px;
    border-top: 2px white solid;
    }
    
#topnav ul { 
    margin-top: 0;
    float: left; 
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

#topnav ul li { 
    display: inline; 
    background-color: #339999;
    }
    
#topnav ul li a { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left; 
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px; 
    width: 140px;
    }
    
#topnav a:link      { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:visited   { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:active    { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav a:hover     { background-color: #0077CC; }
#topnav a:focus     { color:#ffffff; }

#subbanner {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #2687D7; 
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    }

#subbanner h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#subbanner p { 
    margin: 0px 150px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    }
     
#dobrodosli { 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;  
    margin-right: 15px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-top-style: outset;
    border-right-style: inset;
    border-bottom-style: inset;
    border-left-style: outset;
    border-top-color: DodgerBlue;
    border-left-color: DodgerBlue;
    border-right-color: Cyan;
    border-bottom-color: Cyan;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align: middle;
    }
        
#picture1           { 
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-top-style:outset;
    border-right-style:inset;
    border-bottom-style:inset;
    border-left-style: outset;
    border-top-color: cyan;
    border-left-color: cyan;
    border-right-color: DodgerBlue;
    border-bottom-color: DodgerBlue;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="Slike/logo2.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Zdravstvena ustanova</h1>
            <h1>stomatolo&#353;ka ambulanta</h1>
            <hr/>
            <h1>M O D E N T &nbsp; &nbsp; L O P A R E</h1>
            <p>Cara Du&#353;ana 32 A Lopare</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Naslovna</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">O nama</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">Tim</a></li>
            <li><a href="galerija.html">Galerija</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="subbanner">
        <h2>Dobrodo&#353;li u Modent!</h2><br />
        <img id="dobrodosli" src="Slike/dobrodosli.jpg" /><img id="picture1" src="Slike/op_1.jpg" />
        <p>Zdravstvena ustanova stomatoloska ambulanta <b><i>MODENT Lopare</i></b> pocela je sa radom 03.02.2004. </p>
```